# Template class optimizations during compiling

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compilation

I was curious to know the internals of template class compilation in specific circumstances. I ask this because I'd like to extend some existing classes.

For example, let's assume a starting

```
template<typename T>
class LargeClass {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> data;
    // many other fields

  public:
    const std::unique_ptr<T>& getData() { return data; }
    void setData(T* value) { data.reset(value); }
    // many other methods that don't depend on T
}
```

This example makes me think that, since `sizeof(std::unique_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*)` (without a custom deleter) then `sizeof(LargeClass<T1>) == sizeof(LargeClass<T2>)` for any T1 and T2. Which implies that all `offsetof(field, LargeClass<T>)` are the same for any field and T.

So why the compiler would create a copy of each `LargeClass` method if they don't depend on `T`?

A different approach, like

```
class LargeClass {
  private:
    T data
    ...

  private
    ...
}
```

instead should force the compiler to create multiple definitions of the methods for different types since `sizeof(T)` could change, but using an `std::aligned_storage` with a `static_assert` (to avoid storing too large data) could make this fallback to the first case. Would a compiler be smart enough to realise it?

In general I was wondering if a compiler is smart enough to avoid generating multiple definition of a template class method if the type variable is not used and the class structure doesn't change (or at least doesn't change for accessing the fields accessed in the method) or not. Does the standard enforce anything about it?

Comment: [It's possible for the optimizer/linker to "merge" functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918414/c-templates-convincing-self-against-code-bloat) that are effectively equivalent.

Comment: "So why the compiler would create a copy of each LargeClass method if
they don't depend on T?"

Who said it will ?? The linker does great job, don't worry

Comment: Do not try to help the compiler : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4     , not a direct answer to your question but still should know about this.